# It is possible to generate the apk by neglecting some of the image files attached in resource folder

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, apk, android-install-apk

Need to exclude some of the image files in the resource file of class library when creating apk files.

Comment: The Gradle build system for Android supports "resource shrinking": the automatic removal of resources that are unused, at build time, in the packaged app.

Comment: It supports xamarin forms?. And its a control. If the resource is not used in application level means, need to remove it from source while generating APK

Comment: Could you give some more details on the project structure and the exact use-case? The answer might depend on that. The way this question is posed right now makes it hard to give a useful answer.

Comment: You can use build flavours http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors

Comment: Eg:

Currently am developing a control, have a Xamarin forms class library and attached nearly 20 images in Xamarin android, iOS and UWP project.

User allows to select an image (from enum property) in sample level.

So, I want to remove the other images which are not used in the application level from APK, IPA or exe generation. Is this possible in xamarin forms project for all platforms?

Comment: As i know, we could select an existing resource in the settings grid (described below) and click Remove Resources to delete it. But i do not find the way to delete programlly.